# Adding Text File through Apps Script adds second"

Tags: google-apps-script, copy-paste

I have a scrip that is adding in HTM into a cell that it copies from a text file.

The script goes to the Google Drive location, copies the html text in the txt file and then pastes it into a cell.

When I go to have the code placed in the html viewer it ads an additional " into the code. Viewing the code in the Google sheet shows it correctly. It is only when copy and pasted into the html view that the second " is found. It is also found when pasting the code into the site.

If I copy the script from going into the formula bar and selecting all than it works in the HTML viewer. It is only when copying the cell by selecting it.

Example:

Correct paste -

```
<td><a href="https://www.google.com/search?kgmid=/g/1tl0xlq3"><img src="https://www.google.com/maps/vt/data=0VFu_F4Bx-5lwDGqJYDI6I6tr3Mbedx2smpbqtdC1yluR4_Fj3hhz7AXWCuAx5aYEfLwo_4E6ruoO-RpRwz5cFXCO_UGm2leq-0C_3I" width="262" height="175"><br>Sycamore Drive</a></td>
```

What happens when pasted into html viewer from copy and pasting by selecting the cell:

```html
<td><a href=""https://www.google.com/search?kgmid=/g/1tl0xlq3""><img src=""https://www.google.com/maps/vt/data=0VFu_F4Bx-5lwDGqJYDI6I6tr3Mbedx2smpbqtdC1yluR4_Fj3hhz7AXWCuAx5aYEfLwo_4E6ruoO-RpRwz5cFXCO_UGm2leq-0C_3I"" width=""262"" height=""175""><br>Sycamore Drive</a></td>
```

This is the script to grab the text from the google folder.

```
function importTextFilesAsValues() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('google folder ID');
  var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = 2;

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var content = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    sheet.getRange(row, 1).setValue(content).setNumberFormat("@");
    row++;
  }
}
```

I tried copy and pasting the cell which did not work. Only when copying the text by doing it through the formula bar it works.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand `When I go to have the code placed in the html viewer it ads an additional " into the code. Viewing the code in the Google sheet shows it correctly. It is only when copy and pasted into the html view that the second " is found. It is also found when pasting the code into the site. If I copy the script from going into the formula bar and selecting all than it works in the HTML viewer. It is only when copying the cell by selecting it.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: When I copy and paste the code here: https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer you can see the issue.